# What is the verification process with OpenSSL PKCS7_NOCHAIN flag

Tags: openssl, certificate, ca

Im confused with the meaning of OpenSSL verify flag PKCS7_NOCHAIN. By definition it says:

> If PKCS7_NOCHAIN is set then the certificates contained in the message
>   are not used as untrusted CAs. This means that the whole verify chain
>   (apart from the signer's certificate) must be contained in the trusted
>   store.

"certificates contained in the message are not used as untrusted CAs" and "whole verify chain must be contained in the trusted store"

Normally the verification walks through the chain verifying the issuer/root ca certificates. What changes with PKCS7_NOCHAIN flag?

Based on the doc here seems like it directs OpenSSL to trust the certificate issuer and not to validate the issuer walking the chain. https://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.pkcs7.flags.php

Answer (score 0):

A message is signed by a single signer's certificate, but might include more than one certificate. Typically this happens when the signer's certificate is issued by an intermediate, signed by one the root certificates from the trusted store.

Typical verification process is as following:

1. Find the signer's certificate in the certifacates attached to the message. Verify it (check purpose, check not before, check not after, etc.)
2. Find the issuer's certificate either in the trusted store OR among the attached certificates. Verify the certificate and verify the signature of the signer's certificate.
3. Do the same for the issuer of the issuer and so on until you reach a self-signed certificate.
4. The terminating self-signed sertificate must be in the trusted store.

The option `PKCS7_NOCHAIN` modifies steps 2 and 3: intermediate certificates are searched in the trusted store **only**. Attached certificated are ignored.

Proof:
Function `PKCS7_verify` in the [file pk7_smime.c, line 272](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/454afd9866300b984306c5b565a9d55568a5bc50/crypto/pkcs7/pk7_smime.c#L272)
If flag `PKCS7_NOCHAIN` is not set, then certificates from the message are added as `chain` in the call to `X509_STORE_CTX_init`.

> The trusted certificate store is set to **store**, the end entity
>   certificate to be verified is set to x509 and a set of additional
>   certificates (which will be untrusted but may be used to build the
>   chain) in **chain**.

If `PKCS7_NOCHAIN` is set, then `chain` argument of `X509_STORE_CTX_init` is `NULL` - the cetificates attached to the message are ignored.